# What does the colon in the styles tab of Chrome dev tools mean?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome-devtools

I googled the heck out of this and could not word my search properly to find the answer. I'm working on a Wordpress site that is letting me edit the stylesheet (style.css) via the Editor, but the changes aren't appearing on the website, the old css is still being shown for some reason. I have cleared my browser cache to no avail.

Anyway....

Using Chrome's dev tools show the old styles are being pulled from things like style.css:90, style.css:400, style.css:9, etc...

What does that mean? Where are those numbers coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the numbers the line numbers from your CSS file? As in the code/style declaration on line 90 and line 400 from your style.css file.

Comment: Yes....hahaha I don't know how I didn't notice that. Most of the sites I work have css that gets pulled from a minified file so it only ever shows :1